# Why is my price column getting replaced when I try to drop a specific row?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am cleaning a google Playstore reviews dataset. It contains details of over 10k apps with columns like app name, price, reviews, installs and a few more cols. There is a row in which the data is displaced and the price column contains the value 'Everyone' instead of a price value.

I tried to replace it with

```
df_path['Price'] = df_path[df_path.Price != 'Everyone']
```

And after I did this, I noticed that the row got dropped when I checked with

```
df_path.info()
```

After this, when I take value counts using

```
df_path.Price.value_counts()
```

Something seriously wrong happens. The Price column gets replaced with the values of column names.
And this isn't the only method I've tried to remove that row. I also tried using the df.drop() command and the same thing happens. And the worst part is that it shows the data type as int64 after this happens. Refer to the image link below for reference.

What am I doing wrong? [Price col gets replaced with the app names and type is int64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bctBe.png)
[The row which has the value 'Everyone' in the price column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acbrK.png)

Comment: If you want to replace, perhaps try using `replace()`? check the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: What is the index of the dataframe? I ask because if you are going to use df.drop you'll need the index value for the row you are going to drop.

Comment: @IvanWiryadi I'm not trying to replace, I'm trying to remove

Comment: @PaulaThomas The index is a standard index, ranging from 0 to 10841. The index of this particular row is 10472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are want to drop that row, try this:

```
df_path = df_path[df_path.Price != 'Everyone']
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But I still don't get why my previous command replaced all the values in that row and why (or rather how) the dtype changed from object to int64. (:

Comment: The screenshot shows that the count column has a dtype of int64 (which is to be expected). This does not mean that the column itself (`Price`) has a dtype of int64. What do you get when you run `df['Price'].dtype`

Comment: It says dtype('O'), which corresponds to Object, I presume.